# Simple password hashing program c++

Tags: c++

Im trying to add the output together. So instead of the output being 12 I want it to be 3, but I have no idea how to. Help is much appreciated.

```
int returnVal(char x)
{
return x - 96;
}


int main() {
string s = "ab";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    cout << returnVal(s[i]);    
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the return value to a running total?

Comment: Thats what I thought! Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Create a variable of the right type, zero it, and then add `returnVal(s[i])` to it in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value of the total.

[EXAMPLE]:

```
int returnVal(char x)
{
    return x - 96;
}

int main() 
{
    string s = "ab";
    int totalValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        totalValue += returnVal(s[i]);        
    }
    cout << totalValue; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "ab";

    std::cout << std::accumulate( s.begin(), s.end(), 0, []( int i, char c ) {
             return i + returnVal(c);
        } ) << std::endl;
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/JiXMSc)